# Is it possible to comment a review of a suggested edit?

Tags: support, comments, review, suggested-edits, notifications

Recently a not really good suggested edit to my answer was approved. Is there a way how to comment the review or suggested edit to let the reviewer know about the bad decision?

---

The review: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/23074

The edit with a comment says that because Mac keyboards lacks buttons used in the answer the answer applies only to Windows. Hey, are Mac and Windows the only operating systems on this world? :-)

Comment: Side note, what's a mod doing with an approval rate that high.  Either web apps apparently has way better suggested edits than SO, or that mod is way too trigger happy on approving suggested edits.

Comment: Also… which of those buttons isn’t available on a Mac?

Comment: @minitech *gads!* my Mac's buttons fell loose from laughter. @ pabouk  Linux users use only the mouse ( Google " linux ratpoison " ). Meh! Sorry, but that reviewer needs to go before the comfy chair.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no way of responding to the reviewer.  You can respond to the person that suggested the edit, but not those that approved/rejected it.

If you notice a problematic reviewer you can flag the post and have a moderator look into the issue, but this would be something that you would do if you are noticing a pattern of bad behavior from a reviewer, not for a single review that you disagree with.

If you wish to discuss the review in general, you could post about it on the meta site (note that would be the site specific meta, not this meta), but you have no way of forcing the reviewer to join the discussion, or even of notifying them about the existence of the discussion.  (This is a bit of a special case in that it's a mod, so they're pretty likely to notice a meta discussion about them, or be told of it from another mod.)

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way to respond to the reviewer.  However, if the suggested edit is really not a good one, you do have the capability to "roll it back".

Comment: I don't see 'roll-back' listed under the privilege levels. Is it part of editing generally, or higher ?

Comment: @HowardPautz Rolling back requires full editing privileges.

Comment: @Howard Pautz: You can always edit your own posts.

Comment: @chirlu yes, but there's a grey area, a 'friction zone' if you will, so that's not necessarily a good idea if the edits you disagree with are not obvious or are nit picky on the editor's part. I had one recent post edited by (I think) a non-native speaker. The edit dumbed down my clearer grammar, changed the meaning some, but really didn't matter to the readers. As a professional writer, it irked me. I knew better, but shrugged it off. The flip side: Servy clearly pointed out as questionable an edit I did recently. (continued...)

Comment: ... I corrected the offending section, instead of the OP having to do so. But if say, I had not agreed with the OP, it would have been too time consuming to go back and forth.